# Contract <contract_name> should be marked abstract - when inheriting IERC721?

Tags: solidity, erc-721

I was trying to do a simple NFT locking mechanism when I came across this error (It transfers over the NFT from owner to a locking address): `TypeError: Contract "locker" should be marked as abstract.`

Here is the code.

```
contract locker is IERC721
{
    function lockThisToken(address nftAddress, uint tokenID) public
    {
        IERC721(nftAddress).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenID);
        
    }
}
```

What I understand is I must implement every method in the interface, this is quite fascinating - why would this be a strict rule from a program design perspective?

Also, when this user writes a [similar code](https://solidity-by-example.org/defi/vault) but for ERC20s, it does not return an error - any reasons why?

ref link: https://solidity-by-example.org/defi/vault

Comment: you are inheriting from an interface that has functions but those functions need to be implemented by you. I think you don't need "is IERC721". importing it just at the start of the contract is enough

Comment: @Majd TL has given the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should understand the difference between an abstract contract, an interface and an implementation.

- Interface: contains no function implementations, only function signatures.
- Implementation: contains only function implementations. Can't include functions without an implementation (so the function has to have at least an empty implementation: `{ }`)
- Abstract contract: Can contain both implementations and only signatures. This form is not used very often

Since you are *implementing an interface* (denoted by `is IERC721`) you have to explicitly include each function. Typically you have the function implementation code (although it can be empty) also, but abstract contracts allow you to only list the signature with no functionality (basically the same way as is written in the interface).

In your ERC20 example, the user is writing an interface and then using the interface (but not with `is IERC20`). If the `Vault` was written as `Vault is IERC20` then it would have to include all of the interface functions.